# MYSQL on how to insert value into a specific column table

Tags: mysql

This is my table name `mam_zip`

Columns are `id, zipcode, cityname, countryname, statename, stateabbr, category`

**For example:**

**Pseudo code:**

```
if statename = 'New York' then insert 'Regional' in category
if statename = 'California' then insert 'National' in category
```

Is there a shorter way to insert values in SQL so that I will not manually inserting values in column table category because this has a lot of records

Comment: These appear to be UPDATEs rather than INSERTs !?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use an insert query like so

```
insert into  mam_zip (category) values (regional)
```

or simply do an update

```
update mam_zip
where statename = 'New York' 
set catergory = 'Regional'
```

Cheers

Comment: this works

update mam_zip
set catergory = 'Regional'
where statename = 'New York' 

thanks @Shalvin

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using case when

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5b3642a918d551965772b14a62fff4f6)

you need to insert your values for other columns

```
insert into mam_zip(id, zipcode, cityname, countryname, statename, stateabbr, category)

values(id,zipcode,cityname,countryname,statename,stateabbr, 
case when statename='New York' then 'Regional'
when statename='California' then 'Natioanal' else statename end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query that would conditionally populates your `category` column.

```
INSERT INTO mam_zip (<otherColumns....>,category)
SELECT <OtherColumns>,
        CASE 
        WHEN statename = 'New York'
            THEN 'Regional'
        WHEN statename = 'California'
            THEN 'National'
        END
```